# How to enable move semantics when adding custom objects to a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Below code passes objects that contain big vectors into a vector. I want this to be performant. Do I need to cast `test` to rvalue in the call to `push_back`? Do I need to tell compiler how to move instances of struct `Test`? Or does this all go automatically?

```
int main()
{
    struct Test
    {
        std::vector<size_t> vals;
        double sum;
    };
    std::vector<Test> vecOfTest;
    vecOfTest.reserve(100000);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        Test test{};
        test.vals.reserve(i);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            test.vals.push_back(j);
            test.sum += j;
        }
        vecOfTest.push_back(test);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just do `vecOfTest.emplace_back(std::move(test));` and you should be good. The compiler auto-generates an appropriate move constructor for `Test` because all its members are trivial or have a move constructor.

Comment: every resonable compiler should "see" that `test` is just at the end of it's lifetime and move anyway.

Comment: @Swordfish The standard does not allow that, so if this causes an observable difference the compiler is not allowed to do it.

Comment: @nwp a compiler \*is\* allowed to do that. as-if rule.

Comment: "As if" rule means if the result is "as if" a copy was made. Hence I said "if it causes an observable difference" which means it does not behave "as if" and is thus not covered by the "as if" rule.

Comment: @nwp there is no observable difference.

Comment: @Swordfish Most compilers consider normal memory allocation an observable side effect (involves a system call).

Comment: @Swordfish msvc/gcc are not reasonable, then?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Is there a reason why you prefer emplace_back(std::move(test)) over push_back(std::move(test))?

Comment: @user6556709 It's one temporary less (conceptionally, not that it would matter in practice). `push_back` takes a `Test` (move-constructed from `test`) and copy-constructs it into the vector. `emplace_back` move-constructs it directly into the vector from `test`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof It shouldn't make *any* difference if you push or emplace an *already constructed* object. The temporary is saved, if you have `SomeClass sc(7, 10, 12); v.push_back(std::move(sc));` vs. `v.emplace_back(7, 10, 12)`.

Comment: @Aconcagua You're right. The `T&&` overload of `push_back` handles it with just one move construction.

Comment: @fdan https://godbolt.org/z/CnERjU no moving, sure ...

Comment: @Swordfish I cannot understand assembly, sorry. I see your code doesn't do the rvalue cast in the link doesn't do the rvalue cast. Is it easy to add it and figure out whether that will make the move happen?

Comment: @willem it doesn't matter. as-if.

Comment: @Swordfish: You say it doesn't matter. Do you mean there will be a move with & without std::move, or do you mean there will be a copy with & without std::move. In your last comment, you say  "no moving, sure". But in your earlier comment, you say it will move regardless. Is the second comment a typo;  should it be  "no copying"? Also, if your comments are correct, than none of the answers to this question answer the question I have in the OP correctly.

Comment: @willem *In your last comment, you say "no moving, sure"* – I tried being sarcastic ;) The point is, it is up to the compiler implementation what they do as long as the observable behaviour conforms with the standard.

Comment: I guess I missed the understanding to spot the sarcasm :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Test` struct does not define any special member functions (copy constructor, destructor, etc.) That means a default move assignment operator and a default move copy constructor are generated automatically, and they will move each data member of the struct. So `Test` is a movable type, and it benefits from that since `vector<size_t>` is a movable data member.

However, moves are not performed automatically because moving from an object changes it. Even though you'd think that this:

```
    vecOfTest.push_back(test);
}
```

would do an implicit move because the scope ends, it will not. Implicit moves would put both the compiler and the programmer in a difficult situation. The compiler would be required to prove that invalidating `test` is OK. The programmer would be required to constantly investigate whether or not an explicit move is needed or not, and the end result of that would be to just do explicit moves anyway. So for that reason, implicit moves do not happen (but see below for the exception to the rule.) You need to do it yourself:

```
vecOfTest.push_back(std::move(test));
```

The only case where you need to not move is when the move would interfere with elision. For example, in a function that returns a `Test`, this:

```
Test test;
return std::move(test);
```

would move, but it's better not to. It's better to:

```
return test;
```

instead. This is not an implicit move. It's an elision. Elision is faster than move, and doing a move would prevent elision. However, in cases where elision is not possible, then an implicit move is performed. This is the only case I know of where an implicit move will happen: as a substitute for elision. Your original code:

```
vecOfTest.push_back(test);
```

is not a case for elision, and so an implicit move will never happen.

Answer (score 4):

> I want this to be performant

Following should be good enough. I hope the comments will help you to understand the code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

struct Test
{
    std::vector<size_t> vals;
    double sum = 0; // initialing is a good idea
    Test(const size_t v, const double res) // provide constructor(appropriate one)
        : vals(v), // tell the size of the vals directly in the constructor
          sum(res) 
    {}
};

int main()
{

    std::vector<Test> vecOfTest;
    vecOfTest.reserve(100000);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        // Test& last_test = vecOfTest.emplace_back() needs C++17, otherwise
        // use std::vector::back()
        auto& last_test = vecOfTest.emplace_back(   // create the Test object in place and take the reference to it
            i,                     // tell the size of vals in newly creating Test object
            ((i - 1) * i) / 2.0    // ((j-1) * j)/2 = sum from 0 to j-1
        );
        std::iota(std::begin(last_test.vals), std::end(last_test.vals), static_cast<size_t>(0)); // populate, 0 to size of vals
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even better would be first emplacing the object in `vecOfTest` and then filling the object's vector directly...

Comment: `* 0.5`: You needlessly introduce floating point operations. Don't do that if you don't need to, just have `/ 2` instead.

Comment: @Aconcagua Honestly I have not got your first point. Isn't the same what OP is doing?

Comment: @Aconcagua `((i - 1) * i)/2` could overflow where the manual sum didn't... Also, the original code _did_ accumulate in a `double` variable, so using the sum formula doesn't actually "introduce" floating point operations. And multiplying by 0.5 is about as benign as it gets for floating point math.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I have got some warnings of conversion from in `int` to `double`, so changed back.

Comment: @UsingCpp : Interesting to see what you done to my code to make it as performant as possible :-). Though I said: "performant", not "optimize the hell out of this". I was actually wondering what I could do to avoid the copying of the large vectors, without completely refactoring the code? Or is that automatically?

Comment: @MaxLanghof It wasn't me to introduce the multiplication; but as done on `size_t` it *will* overflow no matter if using `*.5` or `/2` *afterwards*! If really overflow occurs, then the sum in the double value is inaccurate anyway (double offers less precision than 64-bit size_t – assuming we have such). To get around any such issues: `uint64_t n = i; sum = n&1 ? (n - 1) / 2 * n : n/2*(n-1);`. We might add additional overflow detection if `n` really is too large (`sum < n` might do, but need to evaluate further); that would be far better than inexact (double) values without further detection!