# Why C++ implicit type conversion work's well with structures but in other way with classes

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, c++17

I'm trying to create a multi-dimensional array with dynamic memory initialisation in C++, but an implicit type conversion works in one way when I work directly with functions, but in another way when I tried to create class-shell around this pointer and named functions as class members.

If template type T, for example, int, with structures it prefers (T *&) type over (T &) for a pointer of any nesting, but when I made these functions class members, they even can't implicitly make T** to (T*&) transformation.

I understand that T***, for instance, is not T&, but empty body function is a bottom of my recursion, that initializes n-dimensional array(pointer, whatever). This conversion works with non-class functions but doesn't work implicitly with clas-member functions.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct NDimensionalArray {
    typedef typename NDimensionalArray<T, N - 1>::type * type;
};

template<typename T>
struct NDimensionalArray<T, 1> {
    typedef T * type;
};

template<typename T>
void initializeNDimensionalArray(T &, size_t) { }

template<typename T>
void initializeNDimensionalArray(T *& arr, size_t n) {
    arr = new T[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        initializeNDimensionalArray(arr[i], n);
}

int main() {

    NDimensionalArray<int, 3>::type arr;
    initializeNDimensionalArray(arr, 2);

}
```

---

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class NDimArray {
public:

        typename NDimensionalArray<T, N>::type arr{ nullptr };

        NDimArray<T, N>::NDimArray() {
           init(arr, 0); //exception, cannot transform T*** to T*&, 
                         //invokes T&                                               
        }

        void init(T &, size_t, int) { }

        void NDimArray<T, N>::init(T *& arr, size_t n) {

           arr = new T[n];

           for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                init(arr[i], n);
        }

}

int main() {
    NDimArray<int, 3> arr(2);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but upper code with class doesn't work in spite of implicit conversion T*** to T*&, which perfectly works with the first main

Comment: It works even with T******* with structure, I can show you expanded version

Comment: Hint: What is the difference in what `T` means between the two cases? Note that it has nothing whatsoever to do with "structures vs classes" -- there is no such thing in C++ as a "structure", there are class types and there are non-class types (like `int`)

Comment: Look, I understand that there's no difference between structure and class in C++, but I have this situation when there is no exception when I'm working directly with function and is an exception when I'm trying to wrap current structure with the class

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm giving you the hint. The difference between the two cases is about what `T` means in the two cases -- and how it's determined (also it's not giving you an "exception" it's giving you a "compile error")

Comment: Aside: Rather than having some huge number of individual allocations, why not do the indexing arithmetic yourself into a `std::vector<T>`?

Comment: why I used (lost !) so much time to help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't** have an implicit conversion from `int ***` to `int* &` in your working example.

Let's expand the types when we use your template.

```
    NDimensionalArray<int, 3>::type arr;
    // a.k.a. 
    NDimensionalArray<int, 2>::type * arr;
    // a.k.a. 
    NDimensionalArray<int, 1>::type ** arr;
    // a.k.a. 
    int *** arr;
```

So when we pass it to `initializeNDimensionalArray`, the deduced type for `T` is `int **`, which substitutes to give you

```
template<>
void initializeNDimensionalArray<int**>(int** *& arr, size_t n) {
    arr = new int**[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        initializeNDimensionalArray<int*>(arr[i], n);
}
```

Which instantiates the template with another argument, `int *`, and so on.

In the case where you wrap it in a class, your `init` gets it's definition of `T` from the same single template parameter that you pass to `NDimensionalArray`, so it doesn't match when you pass an `int ***` to it. You need `init` to be a member template.

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class NDimArray {
public:
    typename NDimensionalArray<T, N>::type arr{ nullptr };

    NDimArray() {
       init(arr, 0);
    }
private:
    // T is the type we want here
    void init(T &, size_t) { }

    // U will be T, T *, T ** etc
    template<typename U>
    void init(U *& arr, size_t n) {
       arr = new U[n];
       for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            init(arr[i], n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**First I try to reproduce your error when compiling**

To get your compilation error it is first needed to do a lot of changes from  the code you given, because it contains several other errors, please next time be more gentle with us ;-)

So for instance with :

```
#include <stddef.h> // size_t

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct NDimensionalArray {
    typedef typename NDimensionalArray<T, N - 1>::type * type;
};

template<typename T>
struct NDimensionalArray<T, 1> {
    typedef T * type;
};


template <typename T, size_t N>
class NDimArray {
public:

        typename NDimensionalArray<T, N>::type arr{ nullptr };

        NDimArray(int) {
           init(arr, 0); //exception, cannot transform T*** to T*&, 
                         //invokes T&                                               
        }

        void init(T &, size_t) { }

        void init(T *& arr, size_t n) {

           arr = new T[n];

           for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                init(arr[i], n);
        }

};

int main() {
    NDimArray<int, 3> arr(2);
}
```

Compilation :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
c.cc: In instantiation of ‘NDimArray<T, N>::NDimArray(int) [with T = int; unsigned int N = 3u]’:
c.cc:38:28:   required from here
c.cc:21:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘NDimensionalArray<int, 3u>::type {aka int***}’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
            init(arr, 0); //exception, cannot transform T*** to T*&,
                 ^~~
c.cc:25:14: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void NDimArray<T, N>::init(T&, size_t) [with T = int; unsigned int N = 3u; size_t = unsigned int]’
         void init(T &, size_t) { }
              ^~~~
c.cc:21:17: error: cannot bind rvalue ‘(int)((NDimArray<int, 3u>*)this)->NDimArray<int, 3u>::arr’ to ‘int&’
            init(arr, 0); //exception, cannot transform T*** to T*&,
                 ^~~
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

To remove the compilation error just modifying the line where it appears replace

```
    NDimArray(int) {
       init(arr, 0); //exception, cannot transform T*** to T*&, 
                     //invokes T&                                               
    }
```

by

```
    NDimArray(int) {
       init(**arr, 0);                                         
    }
```

because already a pointer and a reference are not the same thing, so no chance with a pointer to a pointer, but a reference can be made from a value

Compilation :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

The execution fails because you dereference the *nullptr*

---

**What you want**

But the code you want (without trying to reproduce your error) based on the first case in your question is in fact :

```
#include <stddef.h> // size_t

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct NDimensionalArray {
    typedef typename NDimensionalArray<T, N - 1>::type * type;
};

template<typename T>
struct NDimensionalArray<T, 1> {
    typedef T * type;
};

template<typename T>
void initializeNDimensionalArray(T &, size_t) { }

template<typename T>
void initializeNDimensionalArray(T *& arr, size_t n) {
    arr = new T[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        initializeNDimensionalArray(arr[i], n);
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
class NDimArray {
public:
    typename NDimensionalArray<T, N>::type arr;

    NDimArray(size_t n) {
      initializeNDimensionalArray(arr, n);
    }
};

int main()
{
  NDimArray<int, 3> nd(2);
}
```

Or if you prefer nested definitions :

```
#include <stddef.h> // size_t

template<typename TT, size_t NN>
class NDimArray {
  template<typename T, size_t N>
  struct NDimensionalArray {
    typedef typename NDimensionalArray<T, N - 1>::type * type;
   };

  template<typename T>
  struct NDimensionalArray<T, 1> {
    typedef T * type;
  };

  template<typename T>
  void initializeNDimensionalArray(T &, size_t) { }

  template<typename T>
  void initializeNDimensionalArray(T *& arr, size_t n) {
    arr = new T[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        initializeNDimensionalArray(arr[i], n);
  }

public:
    typename NDimensionalArray<TT, NN>::type arr;

    NDimArray(size_t n) {
      initializeNDimensionalArray(arr, n);
    }
};

int main()
{
  NDimArray<int, 3> nd(2);
}
```

For both of them there is no error/warning during compilation :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra a.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

and no problem at the execution

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

**About your remark**

> If you'll try to initialize created object you will get an exception, so, it doesn't create it properly.

Warning to not confuse the roles

- the template parameter of the class *NDimArray* indicates the number of dimensions (3 in `NDimArray<int, 3> arr(2);`)
- the parameter of its constructor indicates the number of elements in each dimension (2 in `NDimArray<int, 3> arr(2);`)

The initialization/allocations are correct. Example of a new definition for *main* :

```
int main()
{
  const size_t dimsz = 2;
  NDimArray<int, 3> nd(dimsz);

  // initialize elements
  for (size_t i = 0; i != dimsz; ++i) 
    for (size_t j = 0; j != dimsz; ++j) 
      for (size_t k = 0; k != dimsz; ++k)
        nd.arr[i][j][k] = i*100+j*10+k;

  // check 
  for (size_t i = 0; i != dimsz; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j != dimsz; ++j)
      for (size_t k = 0; k != dimsz; ++k)
        std::cout << "nd.arr[" << i << "][" << j << "][" << k << "] = " << nd.arr[i][j][k] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra a.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
nd.arr[0][0][0] = 0
nd.arr[0][0][1] = 1
nd.arr[0][1][0] = 10
nd.arr[0][1][1] = 11
nd.arr[1][0][0] = 100
nd.arr[1][0][1] = 101
nd.arr[1][1][0] = 110
nd.arr[1][1][1] = 111
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

**A version without pointers**

Of course it is also possible to not use pointers to implement the multi dimensional array, for instance :

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
struct NDimensionalArray {
  typedef typename NDimensionalArray<T, N - 1, M>::type type[M];
};

template<typename T, size_t M>
struct NDimensionalArray<T, 1, M> {
    typedef T type[M];
};

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
class NDimArray {
public:
  typename NDimensionalArray<T, N, M>::type arr;

  NDimArray() {
    // nothing to do
  }
};

int main()
{
  const size_t dimsz = 2;
  NDimArray<int, 3, dimsz> nd;

  std::cout <<  "sizeof(nd) : " << sizeof(nd) << " (sizeof(int) : " << sizeof(int) << ")" << std::endl;

  // initialize array
  for (size_t i = 0; i != dimsz; ++i) 
    for (size_t j = 0; j != dimsz; ++j) 
      for (size_t k = 0; k != dimsz; ++k)
        nd.arr[i][j][k] = i*100+j*10+k;

  // check 
  for (size_t i = 0; i != dimsz; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j != dimsz; ++j)
      for (size_t k = 0; k != dimsz; ++k)
        std::cout << "nd.arr[" << i << "][" << j << "][" << k << "] = " << nd.arr[i][j][k] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra mda.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
sizeof(nd) : 32 (sizeof(int) : 4)
nd.arr[0][0][0] = 0
nd.arr[0][0][1] = 1
nd.arr[0][1][0] = 10
nd.arr[0][1][1] = 11
nd.arr[1][0][0] = 100
nd.arr[1][0][1] = 101
nd.arr[1][1][0] = 110
nd.arr[1][1][1] = 111
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: yeah, this is exactly that error with an implicit conversion that I wrote in a headline. If you compile first main with the structure you will receive no compilation errors.

Comment: Ok, so how should I handle 6-dimensional array if I need without using dereferencing? The main point of this code is an attempt to create 3-4 dimensional arrays on a free store in a class, without bothering of implementation details. One more time, I understand the difference, but implicit conversion works in non-class function, and it doesn't work in class member's function, that's the point.

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко I edited my answer, that time to (a priori) give the code you wanted to have rather than trying to produce your error at compile time

Comment: Try to compile first main with code and explain why it works then

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко "_try to compile first main with code_" what you mean ? I did for both cases and as I show in my answer there is no error/warning even with the strong options I used when compiling. "_explain why it works then_" that works exactly like the first case in your question, I just defined a template class to have a generic definition. The result is not what you wanted to do ?

Comment: Compile this
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct NDimensionalArray {
    typedef typename NDimensionalArray<T, N - 1>::type * type;
};

template<typename T>
struct NDimensionalArray<T, 1> {
    typedef T * type;
};

template<typename T>
void initializeNDimensionalArray(T &, size_t) { }

template<typename T>
void initializeNDimensionalArray(T *& arr, size_t n) {
    arr = new T[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        initializeNDimensionalArray(arr[i], n);
}

int main() {

    NDimensionalArray<int, 3>::type arr;
    initializeNDimensionalArray(arr, 2);
}

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко this is the first case in your question. That compile and run yes. Why do you ask ?

Comment: Why it does not make implicitly type conversion in class's constructor, as it does in first example

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко you moved the init from _NDimensionalArray_ into _NDimArray_, they do not apply on the same kind of element but you did like if it is the case. Do you understand why the first case works ? You written it or you got it ? I am not sure how to manage your questions

Comment: If you'll try to initialize  created object you will get an exception, so, it doesn't create it properly.

Comment: @АлександрКушниренко no, the creations are correct, probably you confuse number of dimensions and number of elements in them, I edited my answer, look at it

Comment: @bruno Also nice one.

Comment: @UsingCpp thank you, to be frank I was disappointed the OP preferred the other answer

Comment: @UsingCpp btw I saw your answer few days ago about performances ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965806/2458991 ), perhaps you have a better solution than me for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092660/how-to-divide-a-binary-file-to-6-byte-blocks-in-c-or-python-with-fast-speed ?

Comment: bruno, your code is completely right, but I simply missed the point, that class's function instantiates with the argument mentioned in a class template, so I started messing up with explicit type conversion, and entirely forgot that the clue was in many instantiations of one template function. Caleth answer was like the clearest way to make listed code works when init functions are class members, so I think that my initial question was quite obscure.

Comment: @bruno Thanks for the link. But,  to be honest. I love C++ and almost don't like C or C level works. Especially the playing round with bytes and files.