# How to divide a binary file to 6-byte blocks in C++ or Python with fast speed?

Tags: python, c++, binary

I’m reading a file in C++ and Python as a binary file. I need to divide the binary into blocks, each 6 bytes. For example, if my file is 600 bytes, the result should be 100 blocks, each 6 bytes.

I have tried struct (in C++ and Python) and array (Python). None of them divide the binary into blocks of 6 bytes. They can only divide the binary into blocks each power of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.).

The array algorithm was very fast, reading 1 GB of binary data in less than a second as blocks of 4 bytes. In contrast, I used some other methods, but all of them are extremely slow, taking tens of minutes to do it for a few megabytes.

How can I read the binary as blocks of 6 bytes as fast as possible? Any help in either C++ or Python will be great. Thank you.

EDIT - The Code:

```
    struct Block
{
    char data[6];
};

class BinaryData
{
private:
    char data[6];

public:
    BinaryData() {};
    ~BinaryData() {};

    void readBinaryFile(string strFile)
    {
        Block block;
        ifstream binaryFile;
        int size = 0;

        binaryFile.open(strFile, ios::out | ios::binary);
        binaryFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
        size = (int)binaryFile.tellg();
        binaryFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        cout << size << endl;
        while ( (int)binaryFile.tellg() < size )
        {
            cout << binaryFile.tellg() << " , " << size << " , " << 
size - (int)binaryFile.tellg() << endl;
            binaryFile.read((char*)block.data,sizeof(block.data));
            cout << block.data << endl;
            //cin  >> block.data;
            if (size - (int)binaryFile.tellg() > size)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        binaryFile.close();

    }

};
```

Notes :

- in the file the numbers are in big endian ( [remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092660/how-to-divide-a-binary-file-to-6-byte-blocks-in-c-or-python-with-fast-speed/56093635#comment98821826_56092660) )
- the goal is to as fast as possible read them then sort them in ascending order ( [remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092660/how-to-divide-a-binary-file-to-6-byte-blocks-in-c-or-python-with-fast-speed/56093635#comment98821738_56092660) )

Comment: Have you tried reading into `unsigned char[6]` ?

Comment: Without knowing what you actually want to achieve, it is hard to give a proper solution. If you read the file via `data = open(filename, "rb").read()` (or similar) you will get a bytestring and with something like `[data[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(data), n)]` you can get a splitted list or you address each chunk directly via `data[i*width:(i+1)*width]`. But my gut feeling tells me that you try to solve a problem in a very unpythonic way. Especially due to the fact that python does not like iterative task i.e. is very slow if implemented poorly.

Comment: @RichardCritten I've attached the code as an image to the post.

Comment: @ChristianB. I'd like to divide binary into 6-byte blocks, then compare their values and sort them in an ascending order.

Comment: @Behzad what the data is supposed to be, a 6 bytes number ? if yes what about the little/big endian ? The `cout << block.data << endl` is surprizing

Comment: @bruno Ok, I did it.

Comment: Yes it's a number, and it's big endian. Why is it surprising?

Comment: is it external representation of a number or binary ? the `if (size - (int)binaryFile.tellg() > size)  { break; }` is very strange too

Comment: @bruno I'm going to read directly the HEX of the file in 6-byte blocks, and then compare their values and sort them in ascending order.

Comment: the HEX ? how do you produce the file ? writing using format %x ? If it is binary it is not HEX (HEX is '0'..'9' 'a'..'f') Out of that if  you want to sort make a 8bytes int from each 6bytes int and put them in a vector then and use _sort_ (it is a  quicksort)

Comment: @bruno simply, I have a file (i.e. 1G), I want to open it in binary in C++ and then read it in blocks 6-byte to 6-byte. Simply, I want to divide the data in the file into 6-byte blocks. I can read the file directly as binary, HEX, or convert it to decimal first. The priority is speed. What should I do to read the data in blocks, each 6 bytes, in a fast way?

Comment: @Behzad I put a proposal putting the result in a `vector<uint64_t>`, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's start simple, then optimize.

### Simple Loop

```
uint8_t  array1[6];
while (my_file.read((char *) &array1[0], 6))
{
    Process_Block(&array1[0]);
}
```

The above code reads in a file, 6 bytes at a time and sends the block to a function.
Meets the requirements, not very optimal.

### Reading Larger Blocks

Files are streaming devices.  They have an overhead to start streaming, but are very efficient to keep streaming.  In other words, we want to read as much data per transaction to reduce the overhead.

```
static const unsigned int CAPACITY = 6 * 1024;
uint8_t block1[CAPACITY];
while (my_file.read((char *) &block1[0], CAPACITY))
{
    const size_t bytes_read = my_file.gcount();
    const size_t blocks_read = bytes_read / 6;
    uint8_t const * block_pointer = &block1[0];
    while (blocks_read > 0)
    {
        Process_Block(block_pointer);
        block_pointer += 6;
        --blocks_read;
    }
}
```

The above code reads up to 1024 blocks in one transaction.  After reading, each block is sent to a function for processing.

This version is more efficient than the Simple Loop, as it reads more data per transaction.  *Adjust the CAPACITY to find the optimal size on your platform.*

### Loop Unrolling

The previous code reduces the first bottleneck of input transfer speed (although there is still room for optimization).  Another technique is to reduce the overhead of the processing loop by performing more data processing inside the loop.  This is called *loop unrolling*.

```
const size_t bytes_read = my_file.gcount();
const size_t blocks_read = bytes_read / 6;
uint8_t const * block_pointer = &block1[0];
while ((blocks_read / 4) != 0)
{
    Process_Block(block_pointer);
    block_pointer += 6;

    Process_Block(block_pointer);
    block_pointer += 6;

    Process_Block(block_pointer);
    block_pointer += 6;

    Process_Block(block_pointer);
    block_pointer += 6;
    blocks_read -= 4;
}
while (blocks_read > 0)
{
    Process_Block(block_pointer);
    block_pointer += 6;
    --blocks_read;
}
```

You can adjust the quantity of operations in the loop, to see how it affects your program's speed.

### Multi-Threading & Multiple Buffers

Another two techniques for speeding up the reading of the data, are to use multiple threads and multiple buffers.

One thread, an input thread, reads the file into a buffer.  After reading into the first buffer, the thread sets a semaphore indicating there is data to process.  The input thread reads into the next buffer.  This repeats until the data is all read.  (For a challenge, figure out how to reuse the buffers and notify the other thread of which buffers are available).

The second thread is the processing thread.  This processing thread is started first and waits for the first buffer to be completely read.  After the buffer has the data, the processing thread starts processing the data.  After the first buffer has been processed, the processing thread starts on the next buffer.  This repeats until all the buffers have been processed.

The goal here is to use as many buffers as necessary to keep the processing thread running and not waiting.

**Edit 1:  Other techniques**

### Memory Mapped Files

Some operating systems support *memory mapped files*.  The OS reads a portion of the file into memory.  When a location outside the memory is accessed, the OS loads another portion into memory.  Whether this technique improves performance needs to be measured (profiled).

### Parallel Processing & Threading

Adding multiple threads may show negligible performance gain.  Computers have a data bus (data highway) connecting many hardware devices, including memory, file I/O and the processor.  Devices will be paused to let other devices use the data highway.  With multiple cores or processors, one processor may have to wait while the other processor is using the data highway.  This waiting may cause negligible performance gain when using multiple threads or parallel processing.  Also, the operating system has overhead when constructing and maintaining threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try that, the input file is received in argument of the program, as you said I suppose the the 6 bytes values in the file are written in the  big endian order, but I do not make assumption for the program reading the file then sorting and it can be executed on both little and big endian (I check the case at the execution)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits.h> // CHAR_BIT

using namespace std;

#if CHAR_BIT != 8
# error that code supposes a char has 8 bits
#endif

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    cerr << "Usage: " << argv[1] << " <file>" << endl;
  else {
    ifstream in(argv[1], ios::binary);

    if (!in.is_open())
      cerr << "Cannot open " << argv[1] << endl;
    else {
      in.seekg(0, ios::end);

      size_t n = (size_t) in.tellg() / 6;
      vector<uint64_t> values(n);
      uint64_t * p = values.data(); // for performance
      uint64_t * psup = p + n;

      in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

      int i = 1;

      if (*((char *) &i)) {
        // little endian
        unsigned char s[6];
        uint64_t v = 0;

        while (p != psup) {
          if (!in.read((char *) s, 6))
            return -1;
          ((char *) &v)[0] = s[5];
          ((char *) &v)[1] = s[4];
          ((char *) &v)[2] = s[3];
          ((char *) &v)[3] = s[2];
          ((char *) &v)[4] = s[1];
          ((char *) &v)[5] = s[0];
          *p++ = v;
        }
      }
      else {
        // big endian
        uint64_t v = 0;

        while (p != psup) {
          if (!in.read(((char *) &v) + 2, 6))
            return -1;
          *p++ = v;
        }
      }

      cout << "file successfully read" << endl;

      sort(values.begin(), values.end());
      cout << "values sort" << endl;

      // DEBUG, DO ON A SMALL FILE ;-)
      for (auto v : values)
        cout << v << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bruno and Thomas. Your answers are really helpful. I’m working on them and will ask you to please help me if I have more questions.

Comment: @Behzad BTW do not forget to compile in optimize mode (e.g. `-O2` for _g++_)